# Create an Alphabet Song

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

Your goal is to create an alphabet song as text in the following form (in order):

```
A is for <word starting with A>
B is for <word starting with B>
C is for <word starting with C>
...
Z is for <word starting with Z>
```

#### Example output:

```
A is for Apple
B is for Banana
C is for Carrot
D is for Door
E is for Elephant
F is for Frog
G is for Goat
H is for Hat
I is for Icicle
J is for Jelly
K is for Kangaroo
L is for Lovely
M is for Mom
N is for Never
O is for Open
P is for Paste
Q is for Queen
R is for Rice
S is for Star
T is for Test
U is for Underneath
V is for Very
W is for Water
X is for X-ray
Y is for Yellow
Z is for Zipper
```

#### Rules:

- Each "letter" of the song has its own line, so there are 26 lines, and a possible trailing linefeed.
- The output is case-sensitive:

  - The letter at the start of each line must be capitalized.
  - `is for` is lowercase.
  - The chosen word does not need to be capitalized, but may be. All lines should be consistent.
- The chosen word for each line is up to you, but must be a valid English word with at least 3 letters, and it cannot be a conjunction (like `and` or `but`), interjection/exclamation (like `hey` or `yay`), abbreviation (like `XLS`), or a name (like `Jon`).
- Though I doubt anyone would find it shorter, I'd find it acceptable to use a phrase instead of a single word. So if for some reason `S is for Something smells fishy...` is shorter, go for it.
- Put your program's output in your answer, or at least the list of words you used (if there's a link to run your code online, we don't need to see the entire output).
- Shortest code wins

---

<sub>*This challenge was inspired by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Njvulx5N_qE).*</sub>

Comment: I am guessing slang is not allowed, even if listed in proper dictionaries? (e.g. "When she realised she was headed towards the outback again she just pulled a [uey](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uey)!")

Comment: Given some of the answers, [this song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dvPhtNZCj0) by Barenaked Ladies seems relevant.

Comment: @JonathanAllan No slang. Dictionaries contain a lot of things that aren't technically words. Abbreviations is one, slang is another.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork This challenge was inspired by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Njvulx5N_qE).

Comment: It's too bad that this devolved into finding 3 letter words that end in the same letter.

Comment: @12Me21 how is that devolution, is this not code-golf?! If you can find a way to access longer words with fewer bytes just do it! Edit - Find a list of 3-letter words using a set of two middle letters and a set of two end letters and you can beat the single enders (which use a set of seven middles).

Comment: @12Me21 Just because other people are copying each other's methods doesn't mean that there isn't a better one yet to be found.

Comment: There's a couple of answers using an external dictionary. Shouldn't they have to add the size of that file to their code?

Comment: @pipe Like which? The ones using the Linux words file? I'm not sure. What's the meta consensus? Idk, because if you think about Python modules, each one is really a different file, but the Linux file is OS dependent, so that might be an external source, not part of the language.

Comment: If `X is for X-ray` is allowed (where `X` is not a word, but just represents the common letter for an unknown in algebra) and `S is for Something smells fishy...` is also allowed, would `X is for X is a letter` be allowed?

Comment: No. X-ray is a single word, just like twenty-two is a word. Learn your English.

Comment: [Relevant?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duAcSVVqudc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [SOGL 0.8.1](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>60</s> 32 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
χ3½⌠↓-ζ⁄∞Nη6′⁵‘Z{t",t5~r‘ooKo to
```

Explanation:

```
χ3½⌠↓-ζ⁄∞Nη6′⁵‘                   push "niooaaoasoioaiaaaoiineeaei"
               Z{                 for each letter of the uppercase alphabet
                 t                output the letter in a newline (and disable implicit output)
                  ",t5~r‘o        append " is for "
                          o       append the letter
                           Ko     append the 1st letter of the 1st string (the 2nd letters) and remove it
                              to  append "t"
```

This is pretty much [Jonathan Allan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109519/59183), but ported to this language.

Old version: (SOGL 0.8.2)

```
Z"sηΒ…@Ν┘$JP6*š∙╬F▓÷Σ⁷4⌠    ⁹{Tīο⁾α⅝½Χ<▼½Ξμ‚‘θ’»∫wGKO",t5~r‘P≥o

                                                              
Z                                                             push the uppercase alphabet
 "sηΒ…@Ν┘$JP6*š∙╬F▓÷Σ⁷4⌠    ⁹{Tīο⁾α⅝½Χ<▼½Ξμ‚‘                  push the 27 words separated by spaces using the languages english compression (BCD...XYZA)
                                          θ                   split on spaces
                                           ’»∫                repeat 27 times (push 0-based pointer)
                                              w               get the 1-indexed item of the array (so 0 = last, 1 = first, 2 = 2nd,...)
                                               G              put the 1st thing on stack ontop (the alphabet)
                                                K             get the 1st letter and remove it
                                                 O            output it
                                                  ",t5~r‘     push compressed " is for "
                                                         P    append that (and disable last auto-output)
                                                          ≥   put the 1st thing on the stack below everything
                                                           o  append the last thing (the word from the word list)
```

output:

```
A is for against
B is for being
C is for could
D is for down
E is for even
F is for first
G is for good
H is for had
I is for into
J is for just
K is for know
L is for little
M is for much
N is for nothing
O is for other
P is for project
Q is for quite
R is for right
S is for said
T is for their
U is for under
V is for very
W is for with
X is for xavier
Y is for you
Z is for zoo
```

This is not the shortest this language can do, but should be the best with the words hard coded.

Answer (score 62):

## Bash (+coreutils), <del>81</del>, <del>87</del>, <del>82</del>, 78 bytes

Uses the man page for [X](https://linux.die.net/man/7/x), as the source of words.

**Golfed**

```bash
man xyst\  x|&grep -Po '\b[a-z]{4,} '|sed 's/\(.\)/\u\1 is for &/'|sort -uk1,1
```

*EDITS*

- Used a non-existing 'xyst' man page + `|&` to save 5 bytes;
- Saved 4 more bytes, by swapping *sed* and *sort*.

**Test**

```
%man xyst\  x|&grep -Po '\b[a-z]{4,} '|sed 's/\(.\)/\u\1 is for &/'|sort -uk1,1

A is for also 
B is for build 
C is for computing 
D is for distribution 
E is for entry 
F is for following 
G is for graphics 
H is for hierarchical 
I is for implementations 
J is for just 
K is for keyboard 
L is for listing 
M is for manual 
N is for network 
O is for output 
P is for programs 
Q is for quite 
R is for runs 
S is for system 
T is for transparent 
U is for used 
V is for various 
W is for window 
X is for xyst 
Y is for your 
Z is for zeros
```

Comment: Does the name thing apply to _any_ names (i.e. Cities, Continents e.t.c.) or only human names ?

Comment: Yeah. An alphabet song is typically for kids, and they don't use proper nouns.

Comment: Are lsof and xregs words? :)

Comment: @OldBunny2800 should be fixed now

Comment: I looked it up, and yes, xyst is a real word. :)

Comment: Looks like kids are gonna be learning some big words. :D

Comment: ["What is a `man`?!"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/what-is-a-man)

Comment: Have you an online interpreter link? I don't know bash or sed - is the word "xyst" going through the grep somewhere, or would using a 3 letter non-existent page work to save a byte? (Xis and Xat are options).

Comment: @JonathanAllan 
Unfortunately, man page for "x" is not available on TIO, but here is a link 
https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@bmKdQUVlcEqOgAGTWqKUXpRYo6AbkK6jHJEUn6lbFVpvo1Cqo1xSnpiioF@vHaOjFaOrHlMYYKmQWK6TlFymo6QMl84tKFHRLsw11DP//BwA, which uses "man man" instead.

The trick with _xyst_ is that _man xyst_ will complain that there is "No manual entry for xyst" to the stderr, which is then merged into stdout with `|&`, so it can be grepped.

Comment: I've considered using a 3-letter "x"-word instead, but that won't work, as the regexp looks for the 4-letter words (as otherwise the rest of the dictionary would not be correct).

Comment: Yeah, I saw the "4" in the grep and realised there must be invalid strings in there you needed to ignore. Thanks for the link!

Comment: The challenge says "at least 3 letters" though...

Answer (score 36):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>88</s> 77 bytes

-11 bytes thanks to xnor (avoid the zip by traversing the string and counting `c` up from 65)

```python
c=65
for x in'niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei':print'%c is for %c%st'%(c,c,x);c+=1
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcsxDoAgDAXQ3VN0IWhkcdBBw2GaBpK/tAYk4fao4xvekHjsU7ZCnaBeYcbcWjUYozEboClxgj/vAn28E0KlPzhx9fMsQUJfLlnjNsYL)**

(A port of my Jelly answer, when it was 56 bytes.)

```
A is for Ant
B is for Bit
C is for Cot
D is for Dot
E is for Eat
F is for Fat
G is for Gut
H is for Hut
I is for Ist
J is for Jot
K is for Kit
L is for Lot
M is for Mat
N is for Nit
O is for Out
P is for Pat
Q is for Qat
R is for Rot
S is for Sit
T is for Tit
U is for Unt
V is for Vet
W is for Wet
X is for Xat
Y is for Yet
Z is for Zit
```

Comment: I like the method of words that end in t. The iteration can be shortened by [updating `x` in parallel](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcsxDoAgDAXQ3VN0IWhkcdBBw2GaBpK/tAYk4fao4xvekHjsU7ZCnaBeYcbcWjUYozEboClxgj/vAn28E0KlPzhx9fMsQUJfLlnjNsYL).

Comment: Very smart, as ever; thanks!

Comment: What's `Unt`? Can't find that one anywhere

Comment: I don't think `Unt` is a word, but `Ut` is so you can replace the `n` in your literal with `\0` to make this valid and only add on one more byte. Edit nevermind rules say it has to be 3 letters long... hmmm

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw An unt is a European Mole according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unt). An alternative would be ult according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ult) it is not just an abbreviation (which are listed with periods, such as [ult.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ult.)).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh I gotcha, it didn't return any results for me because I don't have access to M-W's unabridged section of their site.

Answer (score 31):

## Bash, <del>78</del>, 69 bytes

#### Aardvarks, Babushkas and Kamikazes !

**Golfed**

```bash
sed -nr '/^[a-z]{9}$/s/(.)/\u\1 is for &/p'</u*/*/*/words|sort -uk1,1
```

*EDITS*

- Got rid of grep, -9 bytes

**Test**

```
%sed -nr '/^[a-z]{9}$/s/(.)/\u\1 is for &/p'</u*/*/*/words|sort -uk1,1

A is for aardvarks
B is for babushkas
C is for cablecast
D is for dachshund
E is for eagerness
F is for fabricate
G is for gabardine
H is for habitable
I is for ibuprofen
J is for jabberers
K is for kamikazes
L is for labelling
M is for macaronis
N is for nailbrush
O is for obedience
P is for pacemaker
Q is for quadrants
R is for rabbinate
S is for sabotaged
T is for tableland
U is for ulcerated
V is for vacancies
W is for wackiness
X is for xylophone
Y is for yachtsman
Z is for zealously
```

Makes use of */usr/share/dict/words*:

> words is a standard file on all Unix and Unix-like operating systems, and is simply a newline-delimited list of dictionary words. It is used, for instance, by spell-checking programs.

Answer (score 14):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>150</s> <s>141</s> <s>117</s> 75 bytes

```powershell
65..90|%{$i=[char]$_;"$i is for $i$('niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei'[$_-65])t"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#BcFBCoAgEAXQq0hMWIukTUJEJxGRIYz@xgHNVXV2e6/ZxZh1fvuHsLvj4uwpbB1BoahTsiLQoBNEmGstAmFUZgFSjByhHYXJLn68u6@1Hw)

Loops from `65` to `90` (i.e., ASCII `A` to `Z`). Each iteration, we turn the integer into the appropriate `char` (i.e., ASCII `65` for `A`), save that into `$i` for use later, string-concatenate that with `is for $i`, and then tack on the middle of the appropriate word. That's done by indexing into a lengthy string (borrowed from [Jonathan Allan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109519/42963)). Finishes off with the letter `t` to make the three letter word.

The resulting strings are all left on the pipeline, and an implicit `Write-Output` at the end prints them with newlines in between.

*Saved a bunch of bytes thanks to [Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod)*
*Borrowed wordlist from [Jonathan Allan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109519/42963)*

Comment: you can remove the first letter of each word (the capital one) and print with `[char]$` [example](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#PcjRCkAwGIbhW1mabJaFohy4Ekljk1@itv8M1z7jQG999T2@rqRs8is@u2lRtqeDiAg4Mh@WROK3bD1gZ4nW6stsYUel0RkENBgE4TX80nZXQcEZB5jwjlFoGR2yuuJpyaUMXxS8v71/AA)

Comment: @Rod Thanks. I coupled that with what I was just working on to change how the loop is calculated and how the indexing is calculated and saved some more yet.

Answer (score 14):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 39 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
;“ẉbẊWS»,⁸K;;”t
“¤ṁp}œḊṄæ®’b6ị“ʠȷ»ØAç"Y
```

**[TryItOnline!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AUwAs///O@KAnOG6iWLhuopXU8K7LOKBuEs7O@KAnXQK4oCcwqThuYFwfcWT4biK4bmEw6bCruKAmWI24buL4oCcyqDIt8K7w5hBw6ciWf//)**

Based on the 56 byte version (two below), but changed words to remove all middle letter `"u"`s so it can index into the dictionary word `"anisole"`*, which has the convenience of having the letters we need all at indexes less than six: `1:a, 2:n 3:i, 4:s, 5:o (6:l), 0:e` (note the `"e"` on the right is at index zero [also 7 and -7 and any other number congruent to 0  mod 7]). It's also early in the dictionary so has only a two rather than the much more common three byte lookup index (`"anisogamete"` would also work for 2).

* The old-school name for the aromatic ether methoxybenzene, often used in perfumes.

```
A is for Ant
B is for Bit
C is for Cot
D is for Dot
E is for Eat
F is for Fat
G is for Got
H is for Hat
I is for Ist
J is for Jot
K is for Kit
L is for Lot
M is for Mat
N is for Nit
O is for Oat
P is for Pat
Q is for Qat
R is for Rot
S is for Sit
T is for Tit
U is for Unt
V is for Vet
W is for Wet
X is for Xat
Y is for Yet
Z is for Zit
```

###How?

```
“¤ṁp}œḊṄæ®’b6ị“ʠȷ»ØAç"Y - Main link: no arguments
“¤ṁp}œḊṄæ®’             - base 250 compressed number -> 75711304811637630759
           b6           - convert to base 6 list
                          -> [           2  ,           3  ,           5  ,           5  ,           1  ,           1  ,           5  ,           1  ,           4  ,           5  ,           3  ,           5  ,           1  ,           3  ,           1  ,           1  ,           1  ,           5  ,           3  ,           3  ,           2  ,           0  ,           0  ,           1  ,           0  ,           3]
              “ʠȷ»      -     word from Jelly's dictionary, "anisole" 
             ị          - index into that
                          -> [          "n" ,          "i" ,          "o" ,          "o" ,          "a" ,          "a" ,          "o" ,          "a" ,          "s" ,          "o" ,          "i" ,          "o" ,          "a" ,          "i" ,          "a" ,          "a" ,          "a" ,          "o" ,          "i" ,          "i" ,          "n" ,          "e" ,          "e" ,          "a" ,          "e" ,          "i"]
                  ØA    - get the uppercase alphabet
                          -> [          "A" ,          "B" ,          "C" ,          "D" ,          "E" ,          "F" ,          "G" ,          "H" ,          "I" ,          "J" ,          "K" ,          "L" ,          "M" ,          "N" ,          "O" ,          "P" ,          "Q" ,          "R" ,          "S" ,          "T" ,          "U" ,          "V" ,          "W" ,          "X" ,          "Y" ,          "Z"]
                    ç"  - zip with last Link (1) as a dyad (i.e. get [f("A", "n"), f("B", "i"), ...]
                          -> ["A is for Ant","B is for Bit","C is for Cot","D is for Dot","E is for Eat","F is for Fat","G is for Got","H is for Hat","I is for Ist","J is for Jot","K is for Kit","L is for Lot","M is for Mat","N is for Nit","O is for Oat","P is for Pat","Q is for Qat","R is for Rot","S is for Sit","T is for Tit","U is for Unt","V is for Vet","W is for Wet","X is for Xat","Y is for Yet","Z is for Zit"]
                      Y - join with line feeds
                        - implicit print

;“ẉbẊWS»,⁸K;;”t - Link 1, make a song line: character X; character Y
 “ẉbẊWS»        - compressed string = " is for"
;               - X (e.g. "A") concatenate that ->  "A is for"
        ,       - pair that with
         ⁸      - the left argument (X) ---------> ["A is for","A"]
          K     - join with spaces -------------->  "A is for A"
           ;    - concatenate with Y (e.g. "n") ->  "A is for An"
             ”t - literal character = "t"
            ;   - concatenate ------------------->  "A is for Ant"
```

---

#### Previous, 46

```
“¤ṪŻIð^ƥ’b4ị⁾sap⁾pt¤ØAż,@K¥€“ẉbẊWS»ØAżYF”e272¦
```

Words all have second letter "s" or "a" and last letter "p" or "t" using a base four lookup in a Cartesian product of "sa" and "pt". **Except** the "U" word, which the code changes to "Use" (using the relatively bulky `F”e272¦` on the end) - if I could find a word list like this that does not have such an exception we'd be looking at **39 bytes**.

Word list:

```
Asp, Bat, Cat, Dap, Eat, Fat, Gap, Hat, Ist, Jat, Kat, Lap, Mat, Nap, Oat, Pat, Qat, Rat, Sat, Tap, Use, Vat, Wat, Xat, Yap, Zap
```

[try this one](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYc6hJQ93rjq62/PwhrhjSx81zEwyebi7@1HjvuLEAiBZUHJoyeEZjkf36Dh4H1r6qGkNUMfDXZ1JD3d1hQcf2g2WinR71DA31cjc6NCy////AwA)

---

###Previous 56 bytes

```
”tṁØA⁺,j“niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei”œs3Z,@K¥€“ẉbẊWS»ØAżY
```

Word list:

```
Ant, Bit, Cot, Dot, Eat, Fat, Gut, Hut, Ist, Jot, Kit, Lot, Mat, Nit, Out, Pat, Qat, Rot, Sit, Tit, Unt, Vet, Wet, Xat, Yet, Zit
```

It is formatted, [give it a go](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYW7Jw52Nh2c4PmrcpZP1qGFOXmZ@fmJiaWlxfmZ@YmZpYmJ@ZmZeampiaiZQ7dHJxcZROg7eh5Y@aloDVPxwV2fSw11d4cGHdgONOLon8v9/AA)

---

###Previous, 83 bytes
“ẉbẊWS»WṁØA⁺żż“¦ịfe$ɲVPġþ¹Øt@ƑƊŀqṁŒƑOɦ⁴ḍẊḤṁr}Ƭ¢b⁻?q&øIụNẎ9eƲi⁸'ıB.;%V,¦İ⁷ẓk½»s5¤K€Y
...let's play "Spot which letter does not have an animal!" there <s>is one, and only one - watch out for the red herring</s> *(a lie, the red herring was xenon, which is an element, obviously not an animal)*, are two five letter words here that are not animals (xenon being one):

```
Aphid, Bison, Camel, Dingo, Eagle, Finch, Gecko, Heron, Indri, Jabot, Koala, Lemur, Mouse, Nyala, Otter, Panda, Quail, Raven, Sloth, Tapir, Urial, Viper, Whale, Xenon, Yapok, Zebra
```

(of course this is formatted correctly, [try it](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AZgAZ///4oCc4bqJYuG6ildTwrtX4bmBw5hB4oG6xbzFvOKAnMKm4buLZmUkybJWUMShw77CucOYdEDGkcaKxYBx4bmBxZLGkU/JpuKBtOG4jeG6iuG4pOG5gXJ9xqzComLigbs/cSbDuEnhu6VO4bqOOWXGsmnigbgnxLFCLjslVizCpsSw4oG34bqTa8K9wrtzNcKkS@KCrFn//w) - I just thought I'd save space)

Comment: `Xenon` is not an animal. I was sure you were making a joke by having `H is for Herring`, but I guess not.

Comment: Heh, it was a lie. Xenon was the obvious one :)

Comment: I think they are thinking of [xenop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenops), which is not in Jelly's dictionary.

Comment: Wonderful idea! But `Uut`?

Comment: @GregMartin I agree, I think you started devolving your words into syllabic grunts.

Comment: @GregMartin Oh, too quick with Google - I saw "Atomic Number 113" but failed to spot it is the symbol not the name... luckily [an unt is a European Mole](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unt)

Comment: What's a `Xat`?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Apparently it's [a type of carved totem pole](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xat)

Comment: I couldn't wait for an explanation so I picked apart the code myself with TIO. That's a genius idea, but I don't think it'll work in many other languages. We'll see...

Comment: You can probably improve the 56-byte version to less than 52 via using base conversion and a lookup table to encode the string of letters.

Comment: @ais523 yes I think I can do 51, working on shortening

Comment: @ais523 actually, nope I can't do 51 due to the chain having multiple nilads. [I've done 53](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYc7JjYfnH5txaMOjxn0Pd3UdWfhwZ7P6o4aZSeYPd3cDpfOKE1Mz80sfNczlAuKShzsbD89wfNS4Syfr0KKjk4uNo3QcvA8tfdS0Bqj24a7OJKAZ4cGHdgMVHd0T@f8/AA).

Comment: @ais523 ...but I've got the newer version down to 50 :D

Comment: Aha, a jabot is "an ornamental frill or ruffle on the front of a shirt or blouse, typically made of lace". Obviously not an animal :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions congratulations!

Comment: @ais523 - turns out you were spot on - that version is now standing at 44 bytes using a base 8 (even though 7 letters) compression and indexing into the Cartesian product of the compressed string of the words "noise" plus "aura" and the letter "t".

Comment: @boboquack thanks, looks like I wasn't quite on the ball. fixed.

Answer (score 10):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>89</s> 87 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to Martin Ender*

```
ApBaCaDoEaFaGeHaIkaJeKiLeMeNeOpPeQaRaSaTiUniVaWeXysYurZi
[A-Z]
¶$& is for $&
^¶

m`$
t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@8/lWOCU6Jzoku@a6JbonuqR6Jmd6JXqnemT6pvql@pfEJAamBiUGJwYkhmalxmWGJ4aUVkcWVoUlckV7agbFct1aJuKmkJmsUJafpGCihpX3KFtXFy5CSpcJf//AwA)

I picked a word for each letter that ends in `t` (some are pretty obscure).

**Explanation**

```
ApBaCaDoEaFaGeHaIkaJeKiLeMeNeOpPeQaRaSaTiUniVaWeXysYurZi
```

Replace the non-existent (empty) input with the text above.

```
[A-Z]
¶$& is for $&
```

Replace each capital letter with `(newline)(itself) is for (itself)`. This results in the text above being split into separate lines like

```
A is for Ap
B is for Ba
C is for Ca
```

... and so on

```
^¶
​
```

However, since the newline was placed *before* each capital, there is a leading newline that must be removed. It is removed in this stage.

```
m`$
t
```

Put a `t` at the end of every line, since every word used in the song ends in `t`.

Comment: You don't need to capture the upper case letter. Just use `$&` or `$0` instead of `$1`. Actually that might also save bytes over my split stage.

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks. What does `$&` do exactly? I didn't see it on the GitHub wiki.

Comment: It's an alias for `$0` (and it's just part of the .NET flavour, as well as most other flavours).

Comment: Using some shorter words to get it down to 83, [try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@8/lWOCU6Jzoku@a6JbonuqR6Fnsleqd6ZPqm@qX6l8QkBqYGJQYnBiSGZoXlhieGpEYmRqVyRXtqBsVy3Vom4qaQmaxQlp@kYKKGlfcoW1cXLkJKlwl//8DAA)

Answer (score 8):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>92</s> 88 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes by borrowing an idea from [Business Cat's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109516/8478).*

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
AddBCDEelFGHItsJetKitLMNetOilPQatRSTUrnVatWXisYesZit
[A-Z]
¶$& is for $&
m` .$
$&ad
G`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@8/lmJLi5Ozimprj5u7hWVLslVrinVni4@uXWuKfmRMQmFgSFBwSWpQXllgSHpFZHJlaHJVZwhXtqBsVy3Vom4qaQmaxQlp@kYKKGldugoKeCpeKWmIKl3uC3v//AA)

Based on [AdmBorkBork's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109503/8478) word list, but I've changed a few more words into ones that end in `ad` to save more bytes on the common suffix.

#### Explanation

```
AddBCDEelFGHItsJetKitLMNetOilPQatRSTUrnVatWXisYesZit
```

Turn the empty (non-existent) input into this string. It contains all the letters as well as the rest of those words which *don't* end in `ad`.

```
[A-Z]
¶$& is for $&
```

Insert a linefeed before each upper case letter and then turn it into `X is for X`.

```
m` .$
$&ad
```

Match the letters which are now by themselves and append `ad` to complete the shortened words.

```
G`.
```

Discard the empty line that was created by inserting a linefeed before `A`.

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, <s>122</s> <s>124</s> <s>127</s> <s>120</s> <s>115</s> 101 bytes

Follows the "standard" `<letter><filler>t` structure.
I tried to come up with words that weren't used before by anyone.
If you see a word that you want me to replace, tell me.

```
foreach(range(A,Z)as$k=>$c)echo"$c is for $c",ceaoaaei0eieeouoaaei0eeaei[$k]?:[I=>ka,U=>ni][$c],"t\n";
```

The newline is represented as `\n` but counted as 1 byte.

---

**Output:**

```
A is for Act
B is for Bet
C is for Cat
D is for Dot
E is for Eat
F is for Fat
G is for Get
H is for Hit
I is for Ikat
J is for Jet
K is for Kit
L is for Let
M is for Met
N is for Not
O is for Out
P is for Pot
Q is for Qat
R is for Rat
S is for Set
T is for Tit
U is for Unit
V is for Vet
W is for Wet
X is for Xat
Y is for Yet
Z is for Zit
```

---

**Weird words:**

- [ikat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ikat):

  > Ikat, or ikkat, is a dyeing technique used to pattern textiles that employs resist dyeing on the yarns prior to dyeing and weaving the fabric.
- [xat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xat):

  > A carved pole erected as a memorial to the dead by some Indians of western North America
- [zit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/zits):

  > a pimple; skin blemish.
- [qat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khat):

  > Catha edulis (khat, qat) is a flowering plant native to the Horn of Africa and the Arabian Peninsula.

Comment: Clever solution I was going to do something similar, glad to see this! +1

Comment: These aren't english words....

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Are you sure? PHP is all written in English, as far as I know.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel things like `vprintf` and `zend_version` are most certainly not english words. Very few of these entities are actually words.

Comment: I think those are in english...

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Since you didn't like my list of English words in English, I made a new list of English words with words that are **definetivelly** written in English!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel It's not that I didn't like it, it's just that it was breaking the rules stated by the OP. I removed my downvote..

Comment: The words are at least 3 letters

Comment: @MatthewRoh Sorry, fixing it

Comment: @MatthewRoh Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed it now. If you see anything needing a fix, tell me.

Comment: I wouldn't call `zit` a weird word, at least, I think everyone should already know what it means.

Comment: I honestly didn't. But English isnt my first language. I can remove the definition if you think it doesn't belong there.

Comment: I dunno about T here...

Comment: @matt https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109530/
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109519/
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109509/ <-- Posted before mine - https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109579/
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109588/
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109595/
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109656/
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109581/
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109678/ <-- Posted after mine.

So far, nobody said anything about those. (Also, tit is a bird: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tit_(bird))

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel hmm ok

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>45</s> <s>42</s> <s>39</s> <s>38</s> <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```
Au'Æå•à¡P°€kš¦zá®•Sè)øvy¬“ÿ€ˆ€‡ ÿt“,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@9Yqn647fDSRw2LDi84tDDg0IZHTWuyjy48tKzq8MJD64DCwYdXaB7eUVZ5aM2jhjmH9wOlT7cBiUcNCxUO7y8Biun8//81L183OTE5IxUA)

**Explanation**

`Au` pushes the uppercase alphabet.
`'Æå` pushes the word `scenario`.
`•à¡P°€kš¦zá®•` pushes the base-10 number `36774474076746444766322426`.
`Sè` uses those digits to index into `scenario`.
`)ø` zips those strings together into the list `[An, Bi, Co, ..., Zi]`

```
v                  # for each element in the list
 y                 # push it
  ¬                # push it's first letter
   “ÿ€ˆ€‡ ÿt“      # push the string "ÿ is for ÿt" 
                   # replacing ÿ with with the top element of the stack
             ,     # print with newline
```

Words used: `['Ant', 'Bit', 'Cot', 'Dot', 'Eat', 'Fat', 'Got', 'Hat', 'Ist', 'Jot', 'Kit', 'Lot', 'Mat', 'Nit', 'Oat', 'Pat', 'Qat', 'Rot', 'Sit', 'Tit', 'Unt', 'Vet', 'Wet', 'Xat', 'Yet', 'Zit']`

**33 byte version using some words I'm unsure about**

```
Au'†Ž•4Ãðzòç•3BSè)øvy¬“ÿ€ˆ€‡ ÿt“,
```

Words: `['Ant', 'Bat', 'Cat', 'Dat', 'Eat', 'Fat', 'Gat', 'Hat', 'Ist', 'Jat', 'Kat', 'Lat', 'Mat', 'Nat', 'Oat', 'Pat', 'Qat', 'Rat', 'Sat', 'Tat', 'Ust', 'Vat', 'Wat', 'Xat', 'Yat', 'Zat']`

Comment: -1 byte by changing the `vy` to for example `ʒ` (since we print, we can use the filter as a foreach). Since this answer is pretty old, the `)ø` should now be `øJ` and the `•à¡P°€kš¦zá®•` should be `•V¢~U∊›v‚FγÞ•`: [try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fsVT9cNvhpY8aFoUdWlQX@qij61HDrrJHDbPczm0@PA8oHHx4xeEdXqcmHVrzqGHO4f2PmtacbgMSjxoWKhzeXwIU0/n/HwA).

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>52</s> 50 bytes

*Collaborated with @ETHproductions*

```
;B£[R`  f `Od"¥¥º"gY]qXÃx
```

Contains many unprintables. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=O0KjW1JgIIkgZo4gYE9kIqWHhISHhIaGpYeKgoSKh4SFhYWEuoWHiYOKImdZXXFYw3g=&input=)

The word list is:

```
All Bar Can Dan Ear Fan Gas Has Ill Jar Kit Led Man Nit Oar Pan Qat Rat Sat Tan Udo Vat War Xis Yes Zit
```

Japt uses the [shoco string compression library](http://ed-von-schleck.github.io/shoco/), which reduces common runs of lowercase letters into by a byte. Here is a full list of all two-letter runs that are condensed into one byte:

```
an,ar,as,at,be,bl,bo,bu,ca,ce,ch,co,da,de,di,do,ed,en,er,es,ha,he,hi,ho,im,in,is,it,le,li,ll,ly,ma,me,mi,mo,nd,ne,ng,nt,of,on,or,ou,ra,re,ri,ro,se,sh,si,st,te,th,ti,to,ul,ur,us,ut,wa,we,wh,wi
```

So the idea is to form a word with one of these pairs for each letter of the alphabet.

```
;B£   [R`  f `    Od"string"gY]qXÃ x
;BmXY{[R" is for "Od"string"gY]qX} x

;                                      // Among other things, set B to "ABC...XYZ".
 B                                     // Split B into chars.
    mXY{                           }   // Map each item X and index Y to the following:
                      "string"gY       //   Take the char at index Y in the compressed str.
                    Od                 //   Decompress.
        [R" is for "            ]      //   Put this in an array with a newline and " is for ".
                                 qX    //   Join on X, giving "\n{X} is for {word}".
                                    x  // Trim. This removes the leading newline.
                                       // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

One interesting thing to note is that while Japt can implicitly decompress a string wrapped in backticks, that's actually a byte longer here because you'd have to grab *two* chars in the decompressed string, rather than one.

Answer (score 6):

### Pyke, <s>55</s> <s>51</s> 48 bytes

```
26.f[1R].C".d"R+E)DGjt@.^.Il 6>( F['h .dRdJl5
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=26.f%5B1R%5D.C%22.d%22R%2BE%29DGjt%40.%5E.Il+2%3E%28+F%5B%27h+.d%02%07%06RdJl5)

Link is for 3 length and doesn't qualify as words include conjunctives.

```
    [1R].C".d"R+E)                            - def function [i):
     1R]                                      -     [1, i]
        .C                                    -    chr(^)
          ".d"R+                              -   ".d"+ ^
                E                             -  eval(^) (dictionary lookup of length 1)
                                              -    gets the `i`th word in the dictionary

26.f[             DGjt@.^.Il 6>(              -  first_26():
    [                                         -     function(i)
                       .^                     -    ^.startswith(v)
                   Gjt@                       -     alphabet[current_iter-1]
                         .Il 6>               -   if ^:
                           l 6>               -    len(function(i)) > 6
                                 F['h .dRdJl5 - for i in ^:
                                  ['h         -     function(i)[0], function(i)
                                      .d      -    "is for" (unprintables 0x02, 0x07, 0x06)
                                        R     -    rotate(^, ^^)
                                         dJ   -   " ".join(^)
                                           l5 -  ^.capitalize()
```

Outputs:

```
A is for available
B is for because
C is for community
D is for download
E is for english
F is for features
G is for getting
H is for hardware
I is for increase
J is for jewelry
K is for kitchen
L is for locations
M is for manufacturer
N is for northern
O is for outdoor
P is for protein
Q is for quickly
R is for religion
S is for surgery
T is for thousands
U is for universal
V is for vehicles
W is for weekend
X is for xenical
Y is for youngest
Z is for zoofilia
```

You can test this outside of Pyke using same algorithm. Requires [dictionary.json](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/blob/master/dictionary.json).

```
import json, string

with open("dictionary.json") as f_obj:
    words=json.load(f_obj)

rtn=[]
i=0
while len(rtn) != 26:
    cur_word=words[i]
    if cur_word[0]==string.lowercase[len(rtn)]:
        if len(cur_word) > 6:
            rtn.append(cur_word)
    i += 1

for i in rtn:
    print("{} is for {}".format(i[0].upper(), i))
```

Comment: No. Also, I get an error running your code.

Comment: `Timeout running code.
BAD EVAL` Make sure you update your "Try it online" link.

Comment: `Z is for zoofilia` I would seriously consider before letting my kids sing this.

Comment: @zeppelin http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35306609#35306609

Comment: For anyone doing a double-take like I did: [english](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/english) is not always capitalized. ;)

Answer (score 6):

### Ruby, <s>93 84 69 63 58</s> 62 bytes

```
?A.upto(?Z){|l|puts l+" is for #{"AnDoIsUn"[/#{l}./]||l+?a}t"}
```

**Output:**

```
A is for Ant
B is for Bat
C is for Cat
D is for Dot
E is for Eat
F is for Fat
G is for Gat
H is for Hat
I is for Ist
J is for Jat
K is for Kat
L is for Lat
M is for Mat
N is for Nat
O is for Oat
P is for Pat
Q is for Qat
R is for Rat
S is for Sat
T is for Tat
U is for Unt
V is for Vat
W is for Wat
X is for Xat
Y is for Yat
Z is for Zat
```

All 3-letter words ending with 't', most of them with 'at'.

### Using controversial words (iat, dat, amp. ump) - 55 bytes:

```
?A.upto(?Z){|l|puts l+" is for "+l+("AU"[l]?"mp":"at")}
```

Still trying to find a pattern, I think it's possible to use just 2 different endings, and simplify everything.

Thanks @Value Ink and @Business cat for helping.

Comment: [Qat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/qat) and Xis (plural of [Xi](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xi)) are words, so you can use them and also reduce your lookup regex to `/#{l}../`

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about something similar but I am away from my PC now, I will definitely check that.

Comment: Actually I was trying to find some 5 letter words for the missing letters: array, essay, inlay... But I am stuck on that. :-(

Comment: [Kat](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kat) is a valid word, so you can remove the special case for `kit`.

Comment: Very nice. Using some of your words could save me 3 bytes, but I can't find valid definitions for all of them. Words like `dat` and `zat`. Where did you find them?

Comment: Originally from wordhippo, double-checked with other sources. Zat is a village in Iran (Wikipedia), Dat is a common abbreviation for "digital audio tape" (Thefreedictionary). "aat" and "uat" seem to be impossible.

Comment: I thought of "dat" and "zat" but they are both the same conjunction (that) and slang, both of which types of words are barred. "amp" and "ump" seem to be abbreviations of "ampere"/"amplify" and "umpire". "IAT" is an acronym, so that's no good either.

Comment: Iat is indeed controversial, I am using "imp" instead. I will check the rest.

Comment: Would using `ikat` instead of `imp` help?

Comment: I don't know, I have to find a pattern, or go back to the first idea.

Answer (score 6):

### ///, 163 bytes

```
/2/ad//1/ is for /A1Add
B1B2
C1C2
D1D2
E1Eat
F1F2
G1Goo
H1H2
I1Irk
J1Job
K1Kob
L1L2
M1M2
N1Nob
O1Owl
P1P2
Q1Qat
R1R2
S1S2
T1T2
U1Use
V1Vat
W1W2
X1X-ray
Y1Yob
Z1Zoo
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#DcvJCoIAFIXh/XkKXyAu594n0EpzaHAedoYGUSBoED29ufnhW/yrqPSDiEn/EaE4z8V5TLMjLt1hgEfPsOfecOBBceTR4NNXBAwMJ54MIcP5hYjRdEfMeGvCRHHmWXHhZfOV1@8bN94UKVNDxkyRM1cULBQly2VExcpQs1Y0bHZz/0PLdps7duPyWdc/)

> Yob - n. - A cruel and brutal fellow

Hm, learned something today...

Comment: In the UK a yob is a lout, a thug, or a boor; more uncouth and rowdy than cruel and brutal.

Comment: In Russian "Yob" is a shortened past form of obscene verb, which, basically, is an equivalent of "f*ck" in English. The more you know...

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>72</s> 68 bytes

#### Code:

```
”–³æéÁéî¹àæÑåêÂ§µ™Ä‚æ†Í„Î¢×†™ƒÛÌ´ŸÄ«©‡¯†‚Ä²‚Ò„©É€ŠÛì„”#vy¬…ÿ€ˆ€‡ð«ì,
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#FY1LCsJAEEQP49bzCe7GMAiCCsaFoChjwJExQcUP6EqoIm68RV9krCz686h@dDa3NbfEnZGJI9UZbwbRggeeWOCIp/mK3tya0VzgzNyOc1RciRR9S244xaN90aNGMrfHpYskeNy6UUpB4sSKpg26bsR63BsMoTXyo@A3VpPLK2o2/Zz/)

#### Explanation

The following code:

```
”–³æéÁéî¹àæÑåêÂ§µ™Ä‚æ†Í„Î¢×†™ƒÛÌ´ŸÄ«©‡¯†‚Ä²‚Ò„©É€ŠÛì„”#
```

pushes this array:

```
['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carol', 'Door', 'Elephant', 'Frog', 'Goat', 'Hat', 'Ice', 'January', 'Key', 'Love', 'Mom', 'Never', 'Open', 'Paste', 'Queen', 'Rice', 'Star', 'Test', 'Underwear', 'Very', 'Water', 'Xanax', 'Yellow', 'Zoloft']
```

And is processed using the following code:

```
vy¬…ÿ€ˆ€‡ð«ì,

vy              # For each string in the array
  ¬             # Get the first letter of that string
   …ÿ€ˆ€‡       # Push the string "ÿ is for" where 'ÿ' is the first letter of the string
         ð«     # Append a space character
           ì    # Prepend this string to the current string from the array
            ,   # Print with a newline
```

Comment: Can you explain why that pushes that array?

Comment: I think 05AB1E has some built in words that can be represented by 2 bytes in a string.

Comment: @12Me21 that's cool! `”–³”=Apple` and `int(–³,214)=23891` but I still don't see the correlation here.

Comment: I believe this is the list: https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/dictionary.py

Comment: @carusocomputing [Here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67457/34388) is a more detailed description of how the compression and decompression works.

Comment: @Adnan ahh... Odd way to index, but it works!

Comment: `January`, `Xanax`, and `Zoloft` are proper names, aren't they?

Answer (score 4):

## Clojure, <s>159</s> 232 bytes

Well, now it's certainly non-competing solution as it would be far easier to hardcode the words used. Putting it out there just for the sake of having *correct* answer (and not using others' list of words).

```
(mapv #(println(str(char %)" is for"(first(re-seq(re-pattern(str" "(char(+ % 32))"+\\w{3,} "))
    (reduce(fn[a b](str a(with-out-str(load-string(str "(doc "b")")))))" xyst "(map str(keys(ns-publics 'clojure.core))))))))(range 65 91))
```

Basically still gets all the functions defined in `clojure.core` namespace, but after that evaluates `doc <function name>` and puts it into string. After that concatenates it into one huge string (with the word `xyst`) and finds appropriate words from there. Should be run in Clojure REPL.

Output:

```
A is for arbitrary
B is for being
C is for changes
D is for determined
E is for exception
F is for failed
G is for given
H is for held
I is for items
J is for java
K is for keys
L is for lazy
M is for must
N is for notified
O is for option
P is for performed
Q is for queued
R is for returns
S is for state
T is for true
U is for uses
V is for validator
W is for were
X is for xyst
Y is for yields
Z is for zero
```

Old solution:

```
(mapv #(println(str(char %)" is for "(some(fn[a](and(=(.charAt a 0)(char(+ % 32)))a))(conj(map str(keys(ns-publics 'clojure.core)))"orb""yes"))))(range 65 91))
```

Comment: `or`, not `orb`, for 1 byte.

Comment: The minimum length is 3 letters

Comment: @mbomb007 updated.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 82 bytes

```
_=>btoa`pb
è¡Záî"Âh*"è1£b:ãÚA¤hJ$âRu^YåÚaæb`.replace(/(.)./g,`$1 is for $&t
`)
```

An anonymous function returning a string. Contains unprintables; here's a version that doesn't:

```
_=>btoa`\x02pb
\x80è\x11¡Z\x18áî"Âh*"è1£b:ãÚA¤hJ$âRu^YåÚaæb`.replace(/(.)./g,`$1 is for $&t
`)
```

This uses @JonathanAllen's technique, using only three-letter words that end in `t`. The string decompresses to `AnBiCoDoEaFaGOHuIsJoKiLoMaNiOuPaQaRoSiTiUnVeWeXaYeZi`.

I tried chaining two-letter pairs like so:

```
Ace
 Bee
  Cee
   Dew
    Ewe
     ...
```

I've now made it all the way to `X` but got stuck on `Y`; as far as I can tell, the only attainable three-letter `X` word is `Xis`, and there's no three-letter word starting with `Ys`.

For the record, the full string was `ceeeweeereueaebiueeiziais`...

Comment: According to Wiktionary, you could use [`uzi`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uzi) and [`tiz`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tiz)...

Comment: @DLosc Great idea. Then you'd have to do `sei`, `ski`, or `sri`, which leaves you with `ree`, `roe`, `rue`, `rye`, which leaves you with... the only three letter `q`-words I can find are `qat`, `qis`, and `qua`. Is there a Wiktionary page with more three-letter words?

Comment: There's a [category](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_three-letter_words) for three-letter words, but it isn't a complete list. For instance, it doesn't contain [que](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/que) (which I only know about because another answer here used it). (Not sure there's a `p`-word that ends with `u`, though.)

Comment: @DLosc I was already using `piu`, so that's not a problem at all :P Thanks!

Comment: Hm. `piu` seems pretty borderline--wiktionary doesn't have it as English, and dictionary.com has it as `più` (dunno how we're considering accents for this challenge). But yeah, `ys_` would be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 97 bytes

```
a@c_:={ToUpperCase@c," is for ",Select[WordList[],#~StringTake~1==c&][[3]],"
"};a/@Alphabet[]<>""
```

Looks in Mathematica's `WordList` for the third word beginning with each letter; this avoids one-letter words and interjections. Has a trailng newline.

```
A is for aardvark
B is for babble
C is for cabala
D is for dabbled
E is for eagerly
F is for fable
G is for gabble
H is for haberdashery
I is for iambus
J is for jabberer
K is for kaleidoscope
L is for label
M is for mac
N is for nacelle
O is for oak
P is for pabulum
Q is for quackery
R is for rabbinate
S is for sable
T is for tabbouleh
U is for udder
V is for vacant
W is for wad
X is for xenophobic
Y is for yachting
Z is for zapper
```

Comment: eep, totally forgot, thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Groovy, <strike>76</strike> 73 bytes

(edited from 76 to 73 bytes, thank you cat)

Inspired by the ruby solution:

```
('A'..'Z').any{i->println"$i is for ${'AntIvyUse'.find(/$i../)?:i+'at'}"}
```

we use `any` instead of each as it is shorter and all the println statements return false. For the special cases in the string, we use String.find which in groovy returns the match or null. On null we use the elvis operator `?:` to return a word ending in `at` instead.

Prints out:

```
A is for Ant
B is for Bat
C is for Cat
D is for Dat
E is for Eat
F is for Fat
G is for Gat
H is for Hat
I is for Ivy
J is for Jat
K is for Kat
L is for Lat
M is for Mat
N is for Nat
O is for Oat
P is for Pat
Q is for Qat
R is for Rat
S is for Sat
T is for Tat
U is for Use
V is for Vat
W is for Wat
X is for Xat
Y is for Yat
Z is for Zat
```

### Groovy, recursion, 74 bytes

```
{i->println"$i is for ${'AntIvyUse'.find(/$i../)?:i+'at'}";call(++i)}('A')
```

prints out the text from the first answer and then throws a PatternFormatException. We call the closure recursively starting with 'A' and incrementing `++char` until the character after `Z` throws the error.

### Groovy, by cheating, 77 bytes

With the risk of being lynched:

```
print 'http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/109502'.toURL().text[21796..22189]
```

i.e. read the data in this page and print out the definition of a valid answer at the beginning. In my defense...it does print out the requested answer...now nobody edit the page...

### Groovy, using 'times', 81 bytes

Building on the python answer with the three letter word pattern:

```
26.times{i,c=i+65->printf"%c is for %c${'niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei'[i]}t\n",c,c}
```

prints:

```
A is for Ant
B is for Bit
C is for Cot
D is for Dot
E is for Eat
F is for Fat
G is for Gut
H is for Hut
I is for Ist
J is for Jot
K is for Kit
L is for Lot
M is for Mat
N is for Nit
O is for Out
P is for Pat
Q is for Qat
R is for Rot
S is for Sit
T is for Tit
U is for Unt
V is for Vet
W is for Wet
X is for Xat
Y is for Yet
Z is for Zit
```

### Groovy, by recursing on main(...), 83 bytes

Assuming we count newlines as one character.

```
i=args?args[0]:'A'
println"$i is for ${'AntIvyUse'.find(/$i../)?:i+'at'}"
main(++i)
```

prints out the text from the first answer and then throws a PatternSyntaxException.

### Groovy, using eachWithIndex, 88 bytes

```
'niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei'.eachWithIndex{c,i->char x=i+65;println "$x is for $x${c}t"}
```

### Groovy, using transpose, 102 bytes

```
['A'..'Z','niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei'as List].transpose().each{println it[0]+" is for ${it.join()}t"}
```

Comment: [Kat](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kat) is a valid word, so you can remove the special case for `kit`.

Comment: edited, thank you. Saved me 3 bytes : )

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, <s>131</s> <s>113</s> <s>82</s> 81 bytes

```
FOR I=1TO 26L$=CHR$(I+64)?L$;" is for ";L$;@niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei[I];"t
NEXT
```

Now using words that in `t`

Comment: Example output?

Comment: It's the same as this one: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109502/create-an-alphabet-song/109530#109530

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 77 bytes

```
•‹T1qA‹rËöf#ùqÈ$>M©ÈñM£r°§°Ü]€¡3¸/©#bÍ'ò7DÉø½D—¹û©˜Ò×•36B3ôvy™¬"ÿ is for ÿ"}»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#AYYAef//4oCi4oC5VDFxQeKAuXLDi8O2ZiPDuXHDiCQ@TcKpw4jDsU3Co3LCsMKnwrDDnF3igqzCoTPCuC/CqSNiw40nw7I3RMOJw7jCvUTigJTCucO7wqnLnMOSw5figKIzNkIzw7R2eeKEosKsIsO/IGlzIGZvciDDvyJ9wrv///Vuby1jYWNoZQ)

Uses the following string compressed:

ASSBINCATDOTEATFATGOTHATILLJOTKITLOTMETNOTOATPATQUEROTSETTITUSEVATWETXISYIPZAP

Converted to Base-214:

```
‹T1qA‹rËöf#ùqÈ$>M©ÈñM£r°§°Ü]€¡3¸/©#bÍ'ò7DÉø½D—¹û©˜Ò×
```

---

Used a list of 3-letter scrabble words: http://wordfinder.yourdictionary.com/letter-words/3

Output is as follows:

```
A is for Ass
B is for Bin
C is for Cat
D is for Dot
E is for Eat
F is for Fat
G is for Got
H is for Hat
I is for Ill
J is for Jot
K is for Kit
L is for Lot
M is for Met
N is for Not
O is for Oat
P is for Pat
Q is for Que
R is for Rot
S is for Set
T is for Tit
U is for Use
V is for Vat
W is for Wet
X is for Xis
Y is for Yip
Z is for Zap
```

Had a 70 byte version, but 2-letter words aren't allowed.

---

Explained:

```
•‹T1qA‹rËöf#ùqÈ$>M©ÈñM£r°§°Ü]€¡3¸/©#bÍ'ò7DÉø½D—¹û©˜Ò×• # Compressed String

36B3ô                   # Decompress, split into 3s.
     v               }  # For each word...
      y™¬"ÿ is for ÿ"   # Take first letter of word, interpolate.
                      » # Print with newlines.
```

Comment: `qui` is not an English word. Looking this up reveals only a Latin word.

Comment: @mbomb007 was supposed to be `Que` I knew there was a 3 letter legal scrabble word, misspelled it.

Comment: Nice words :) `}»` could be replaced with `,`.

Answer (score 2):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), <strike>136</strike> <strike>125</strike> 117 bytes

```
((import lists)(each(split "niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei" "")
#X,C::((print(chr(+ 65 C))"is for"(+(chr(+ 65 C))X "t"))))
```

(Split for readability)

[Try it online!](https://andrakis.github.io/ide2/?code=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)

This is pretty much a port of the Python answer

- Saved 11 bytes by using `each`'s index
- Saved 8 bytes by removing useless call to `(scope #)`

**Output:**

```
A is for Ant
B is for Bit
C is for Cot
D is for Dot
E is for Eat
F is for Fat
G is for Gut
H is for Hut
I is for Ist
J is for Jot
K is for Kit
L is for Lot
M is for Mat
N is for Nit
O is for Out
P is for Pat
Q is for Qat
R is for Rot
S is for Sit
T is for Tit
U is for Unt
V is for Vet
W is for Wet
X is for Xat
Y is for Yet
Z is for Zit
```

Comment: Great name! (I don't, thuffer from a lithp, doethe the language have thuch a thpeech ithue though?)

Comment: Thank you! Nope, the language is fine with pronunciation. It's more that it's a bastardized version of Lisp. I just found Lisp far too difficult to wrap my head around, Lithp is my take on it in a way that makes sense to me. It should be much more readable than most Lisp code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 72 bytes

```perl
say"$_ is for $_",(niooaaoasoioaiaaaoiineeaei=~/./g)[-65+ord],t for A..Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJJJV4hs1ghLb9IQSVeSUcjLzM/PzExP7E4PzM/MTMRyMzMzEtNTUzNtK3T19NP14zWNTPVzi9KidUpAety1NOL@v//X35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDAwA)

Comment: Nice can't think of an alternative approach. You can save a few bytes using `$-++` instead of the trick with `ord` though: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJJJV4hs1ghLb9IQSVeSUcjLzM/PzExP7E4PzM/MTMRyMzMzEtNTUzNtK3T19NP14xW0dXWjtUpAWtx1NOL@v//X35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDAwA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 250 bytes

```
@set s=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
@for %%w in (eon dellium zar jinn lbow hon nat our rk unta not lama nemonic domo uija sycho uay ye ee sunami rn ex rap enophobe ou ugzwang)do @call:c %%w
@exit/b
:c
@echo %s:~0,1% is for %s:~0,1%%1
@set s=%s:~1%
```

Since I was never going to get a decent score, I went for the shortest *humorous* words that I could find:

```
A is for Aeon
B is for Bdellium
C is for Czar
D is for Djinn
E is for Elbow
F is for Fhon
G is for Gnat
H is for Hour
I is for Irk
J is for Junta
K is for Knot
L is for Llama
M is for Mnemonic
N is for Ndomo
O is for Ouija
P is for Psycho
Q is for Quay
R is for Rye
S is for See
T is for Tsunami
U is for Urn
V is for Vex
W is for Wrap
X is for Xenophobe
Y is for You
Z is for Zugzwang
```

Answer (score 1):

## [stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 72 bytes

There are *two* for 72 bytes!

```
65@i$'niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei'{!i#::' is for '+\n+'t'+ +out i 1+@i}"!
{!n#::' is for '+\'niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei'n 65-#+'t'+ +out}65 90 for
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#BcEhDoAwDAXQq3RAUlGFADG1g2AqRvLNfsJWRTj7eG@eR8GmDaR7RCfoCHcCrVav0DdhzVkFXW4@onY106EmxhgC2a3gW9KcPw) Using that awesome pattern. (Before you ask, `++` would be a single token, so `+ +` is used instead.)

Both work by iterating from `65` to `90` and getting the correct character sequence. Notes:

- `#:` is an alias for `chr`
- `#` is an alias for `get`
- `{!...}` is the same as `{ n : ... }` (lambda with `n` as an parameter)

For 73 bytes:

```
'niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei'toarr{e i:65 i+#::' is for '+\e+'t'+ +out}map
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>124</s> 121 bytes

```
String c(){String r="";for(char c=65;c<91;r+=c+" is for "+c+"baaonaiineioaeaoaaeileeaoi".charAt(c++-65)+"t\n");return r;}
```

[Based on *@JonathanAllen*'s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109530/52210), since Java has no fancy built-in dictionary. ;) I tried to find another ending letter for the entire alphabet (like `s` or `n` or `y`), or a middle letter (like `a` or `e`), but most were missing just one or two words, so I ended up using `t` as well. Words are manually chosen from [wordhippo.com](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/ending-with/3-letter-words-t.html).

**Ungolfed:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/ys2qs4)

```
class M{
  static String c(){String r="";for(char c=65;c<91;r+=c+" is for "+c+"baaonaiineioaeaoaaeileeaoi".charAt(c++-65)+"t\n");return r;}

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c());
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A is for Abt
B is for Bat
C is for Cat
D is for Dot
E is for Ent
F is for Fat
G is for Git
H is for Hit
I is for Int
J is for Jet
K is for Kit
L is for Lot
M is for Mat
N is for Net
O is for Oat
P is for Pot
Q is for Qat
R is for Rat
S is for Set
T is for Tit
U is for Ult
V is for Vet
W is for Wet
X is for Xat
Y is for Yot
Z is for Zit
```

Comment: +1 for `+a+++`. I like writing those :P

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>145</s> <s>137</s> 135 bytes

I sacrificed some bytes to pseudo-randomise the output with each run. The idea is to look for lowercase words of at least 3 characters in `/usr/share/dict/words` and then pick one from that list using `id([x])%99`.

```
import re
for x in range(65,91):print("%c is for "%x+re.findall("\n(%c.{3,})"%(x+32),open('/usr/share/dict/words').read())[id([x])%99])
```

Edits

- Removed `title()` as words don't have to be capitalised.
- Changed the regex to `"\n(%c.{3,})"` (+ 3 bytes) to allow removal of `,re.M` (- 5 bytes).

Example output:

```
A is for abacinate
B is for bacchantic
C is for caback
D is for dactylosternal
E is for eagless
F is for factful
G is for gabbroic
H is for hackneyed
I is for iambize
J is for jacutinga
K is for kadaya
L is for labra
M is for macaco
N is for nailwort
O is for oakenshaw
P is for pachysomia
Q is for quachil
R is for racer
S is for sabbath
T is for tabulable
U is for ubication
V is for vagabondism
W is for wabe
X is for xenobiosis
Y is for yacca
Z is for zeed
```

Comment: Not sure they're all valid. For instance, I can't find a definition for `Qohele`,  though a search reveals that it is a book or volume of sacred text.

Comment: Just noticed that my regex doesn't match until the end of each word -- will fix.

Comment: Fixed it. Now only looking for lowercase, complete words to not have names in there.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica 93 Bytes

```
ToUpperCase@#<>" is for "<>Cases[WordList[],s_/; s~StringPart~1==#][[9]]&/@Alphabet[]//Column
```

yields

```
A is for abandoned
B is for babushka
C is for cabin
D is for dactylic
E is for eardrum
F is for fabricator
G is for gadabout
H is for habitation
I is for ice
J is for jackal
K is for kappa
L is for laboratory
M is for macaroni
N is for nagger
O is for oarsman
P is for pachysandra
Q is for quadratic
R is for rabidness
S is for saccharin
T is for tableland
U is for ulcer
V is for vacationist
W is for wadi
X is for xylene
Y is for yammer
Z is for zebra
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 72 bytes

```
c=65;"niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei".any{printf"%c is for %<c%st\n",c++,it}
```

**Output**

```
A is for Ant
B is for Bit
C is for Cot
D is for Dot
E is for Eat
F is for Fat
G is for Gut
H is for Hut
I is for Ist
J is for Jot
K is for Kit
L is for Lot
M is for Mat
N is for Nit
O is for Out
P is for Pat
Q is for Qat
R is for Rot
S is for Sit
T is for Tit
U is for Unt
V is for Vet
W is for Wet
X is for Xat
Y is for Yet
Z is for Zit
```

Answer (score 1):

### GNU sed, 81 + 1(r flag) = 82 bytes

This is a sed implementation of the word list from Jonathan Allan's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109519/42963).

```sed
s:$:AnBiCoDoEaFaGuHuIsJoKiLoMaNiOuPaQaRoSiTiUnVeWeXaYeZi:
s:(.).:\1 is for &t\n:g
```

The words, except the shared ending letter `t`, are given in concatenated form on line 1, and then printed in the requested format by line 2. A trailing newline is present.

**Run**:

```sh
sed -rf alphabet_song.sed <<< ""
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>91</s> <s>87</s> <s>86</s> 76 bytes

based on [Jonathan Allan´s word list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109530/55735):

```php
for($a=A;$i<26;)echo"$a is for ",$a++,neaoaaeiseioeuuoaaiineiaei[$i++],"t
";
```

older versions, 86 bytes:

```php
for($a=A;a&$c=reaoaaei0eioeuuoaaii0eiaei[$i++];)echo"$a is for ",$a++,$c?$c.t:nto,"
";
```

or

```php
for($a=A;$c=reaoaaeiHeioeuuoaaiiHeiaei[$i++];)echo"$a is for ",$a++,$c^x?$c.t:nto,"
";
```

Run with `-nr`.

**output**

```
A is for Art
B is for Bet
C is for Cat
D is for Dot
E is for Eat
F is for Fat
G is for Get
H is for Hit
I is for Into
J is for Jet
K is for Kit
L is for Lot
M is for Met
N is for Nut
O is for Out
P is for Pot
Q is for Qat
R is for Rat
S is for Sit
T is for Tit
U is for Unto
V is for Vet
W is for Wit
X is for Xat
Y is for Yet
Z is for Zit
```

For the weird words, see [Ismael´s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109567#109567)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 38 bytes

```
»hrZ⌈∪≠ẏ¡ɽ»`…„ṙµ`τkAZƛ÷:ðJ«⁼Ė⁼|«Jpp\tJ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiwrtoclrijIjiiKriiaDhuo/Cocm9wrtg4oCm4oCe4bmZwrVgz4RrQVrGm8O3OsOwSsKr4oG8xJbigbx8wqtKcHBcXHRKIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Port of Jelly answer.

### How?

```
»hrZ⌈∪≠ẏ¡ɽ»`…„ṙµ`τkAZƛ÷:ðJ«⁼Ė⁼|«Jpp\tJ
»hrZ⌈∪≠ẏ¡ɽ»                             # Push compressed number 1849391794619481940361
           `…„ṙµ`                       # Push dictionary compressed string "anisole"
                 τ                      # Convert to custom base (this will result in "niooaaoasoioaiaaaoiineeaei")
                  kAZ                   # Zip with the uppercase alphabet
                     ƛ÷:                # For each item, push both to the stack and duplicate the top item (e.g. stack: "n", "A", "A")
                        ðJ              # Add a space to the end of the alphabet letter
                          «⁼Ė⁼|«J       # Concatenate compressed string "is for " to it
                                 pp     # Concatenate the alphabet letter and the other letter to the end (e.g. stack: "A is for An")
                                   \tJ  # Append the letter "t" to the end
                                        # j flag joins the top of the stack on newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 112 bytes

```python
for x in range(26):y=chr(x+65);print y+' is for '+y+'naaoaaeaneieaiaaaaairaeeei'[x:x+1]+('t','n')[x in(8,20,23)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FYwxDoMwDAC/4s2JnKEEFSEqXoIYrMoUL6ZyGcLrQ3PbSaer2@FQQA2c7SMhD3G65vfuodDwjK@vq51wEYL@oLVIfzHmg1nYRIWVG@osIopLmQp1KwU8MaFhXNo9jCk/Uu7jWusN)

All of the words end with 't' except for 3 which end with 'n' so we just store the middle letters of the three letter words and indexes of the 3 'n' words and sort out the 'misfits' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.X, 147 bytes

Yet another try in python using **nltk** -

```
from nltk.corpus import*;k=lambda y:filter(lambda x:y in x[0],words.words());print'\n'.join([chr(i)+' is for '+k(chr(i))[64]for i in range(65,91)])
```

### Output -

```
A is for Abranchiata
B is for Baconic
C is for Cahokia
D is for Damara
E is for Echium
F is for Fascista
G is for Galenic
H is for Halawi
I is for Ichthyornithidae
J is for Jamaica
K is for Kanauji
L is for Lahontan
M is for Macropodinae
N is for Nankingese
O is for Odelsthing
P is for Palaeeudyptes
Q is for Quintius
R is for Rambo
S is for Sac
T is for Tagula
U is for Ulyssean
V is for Vanguardist
W is for Wallon
X is for Xiphodontidae
Y is for Yazoo
Z is for Zea
```

### Ungolfed

```
from nltk.corpus import*
k=lambda y:filter(lambda x:y in x[0],words.words())
print'\n'.join([chr(i)+' is for '+k(chr(i))[27]for i in range(65,91)])
```

Comment: @mbomb007 I used `words` corpus but `brown` corpus can also be used and it is quite better for this problem (but its really yuge). Btw Rambo is actually a word haha - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rambo

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge-93, 73 bytes

This just uses three-letter words, where the last letter is always `t`.

```
naaoaauanoioaefeauoosaeaei:0\55+\"t"\:0g\"A"+:," rof si ">:#,_$1+:55*`#@_
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=bmFhb2FhdWFub2lvYWVmZWF1b29zYWVhZWk6MFw1NStcInQiXDowZ1wiQSIrOiwiIHJvZiBzaSAiPjojLF8kMSs6NTUqYCNAXw&input=)

But with an additional two bytes, we can vary the last letter between `t` and `e` and get a more interesting selection.

```
teuowaeocoaooudouaeosaoaei:"A"+:,0" rof si ">:#,_$,:0g,1+:2%0g,55+,:55*`#@_
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=dGV1b3dhZW9jb2Fvb3Vkb3VhZW9zYW9hZWk6IkEiKzosMCIgcm9mIHNpICI+OiMsXyQsOjBnLDErOjIlMGcsNTUrLDo1NSpgI0Bf&input=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 153 bytes (hardcoded words)

```
“¢r£ẒẸv⁽Ẋ⁷ƥḷṢ⁴kṣe]Ȧ½ṇZṅẸȥɓ!ṗẒ/¿`-¤ḅṘẠṗıBṖ²}çSṘ¦qḤAi\Ḃɲ=T¿?İ®ʋÇIZ(ṅ/ß+oŻ#⁽ƙ©Ḷ!&ẋṡU7FocĊ¶€¢¦ḥLØṀ¿;ȥż!Ọerṫ÷1Ẹjẏ8Ƙ&£ṃṾḊ¿Ṅ⁾ị°ÑBḅQ²€œðḤDẊj£ṅĠsṿBsƤȤ»ṣ”%j“ẉbẊWS»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FZDRSgJhFISfRSIJIqSrgohoiSDoJiwCKYjCizZBUgi6CFxLJA2ihDIoMt01ogiT0P//N104uy5rbzH7Itvpdpgz55vR05nMaRSFhUdq5qgFdQslTkJjAFUJjb5vQfQhm6HxfQTZSu8GbRpAllOQJTYG1rgWg7znswQ5ezNkQpQg61ANVr0vDfKOumfua5JFah9DmMuHOxDFcXdxk5wlr0Ofv1W3vJaa4sCE@zydHdkT/N1/oDeIXiwOVYV82ZpbzR54FeqFxQ9qUhvCWnfrkAVyFgJr9BODfZXOQb67/VnG0qGu5/16nPvIc8ghRIUcyIvQGMKuUse90Zhzg7ocN6q5HcZa4b76v7/kNfKQjpb3zcAkm0uHhadJnQeCutxn13aS7Cj6Aw)

```
A is for Apple
B is for Bald
C is for Cabin
D is for Dairy
E is for Eagle
F is for Fact
G is for Gauge
H is for Humid
I is for Iamb
J is for Jar
K is for Keg
L is for Lad
M is for Music
N is for Nose
O is for Oak
P is for Page
Q is for Quart
R is for Rag
S is for Sock
T is for Taco
U is for Udon
V is for Vault
W is for Week
X is for Xylophone
Y is for Yard
Z is for Zoo
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 85 bytes

[Based on *@JonathanAllen*'s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109530/52210)

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCsIwFEbhvU/xE1pIEQcHHaodfAAncRKHa0zLlZorSSqV0mePcTtn@IKhgZLcn9ZEnIgd5gJ42A6vPJp8Hxocvafv9Rw9u/5WN7g4jmgxpw95mHa3LTrxejqslWMRonEMwkI8Egmzs5Ysq3p@Zx8HpztVmsqAAzLDv8upClHVe7NqN0sClmJJPw)

```scala
var c=65
for(x<-"niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei"){println(f"$c%c is for $c%c$x%st");c+=1}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY67CsJAEEX7fMVlSSBBLCy0CKbwA6zESizGdRNG4m7Yh0Qk3x7z2GJgzuXMZZyklsbRPF5KepyJNX4J8FQ13hPkZBtX4mQtfW8Xb1k396LEVbNHtZjAhyzkRId9xBasuzALQrMxRCE4w4Y4EBlmrRQpFotcG4u8x3G7nhSxcm0xwa81tUhlJsFu8ec97TPnRXS76S3f6nz1i5hKbCrsFhiSeYZkHP8)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var c = 65
    val input = "niooaauusoioaiuaaoiineeaei"
    for (x <- input) {
      val output = f"$c%c is for $c%c$x%st"
      println(output)
      c += 1
    }
  }
}
```